# syncronize instance instead of of volatile primitives

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, thread-safety

I have an object:

```
class Data{
   int a;
   int b;
   AtomicIntegerArray c = new AtomicIntegerArray(10000);   
}
```

this object is used by threads A and B in the following scenario:

A creates a Data (now referred to as "data")

A sends data to a queue.

B reads from the queue, gets data.

B updates data's fields and signals to A that data has been processed.

B sleeps.

A starts working on data's fields.

Now, what I've been doing thus far to ensure memory visibility is:

```
 class Data{
   volatile int a;
   volatile int b;
   volatile AtomicIntegerArray c = new AtomicIntegerArray(10000);   
}
```

This works, but makes me concerned. When Thread A gets back data, it only needs to synchronize it's memory once at the beginning, not every time it touches a field. I'm thinking I can achieve this by simply having A do:

```
synchronized(data){}
```

once it knows that data has been updated, and thus use the first implementation of Data. That way I only do costly memory synchronizations once.

Am I correct? Do I also need to make sure Thread B synchronizes data before "handing it over" to Thread A?

Bare in mind that I'm only interested in memory synchronization/visibility, no locking mechanisms and the signalling between the threads are of no concern. I have that covered.

SIGNALING:

```
class A implements callback{
    private volatile boolean dataProcessed;
    private final Data data = new Data();

    @Override
    public void dataHasBeenProcessed(){
         dataProcessed = true;
    } 

    void someMethod(){
       dataProcessed = false;
       threadB.processData(data, this);
       while(!dataProcessed)
          ...sleep;
       data.workOnFields();

}
```

So, A sends the data to B, then polls a volatile boolean, which B sets in the callback method, when data is processed.

Comment: > B updates data's fields and signals to A that data has been processed.


How is B sending the signal to A? Can you paste that code?

Comment: sure, I've updated

Comment: posted as an Answer. Too big to fit in comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I correct? Do I also need to make sure Thread B synchronizes data before "handing it over" to Thread A?

Since you have established **happens-before** using the `volatile` variable, **you are correct**. If Thread B writes to the **volatile** variable `dataProcessed`, it is making all its memory changes (to `Data`) available to Thread A which reads the same volatile variable.

Since you ask about memory visibility, think of it this way: when Thread B writes to the volatile variable, it is guaranteed to **flush** all the variables it changed (`Data`) to the main memory. (from the CPU core the Thread B is running on). Thread A can now see it all. This is essence of the happens-before relationship.

While it works, this is not a good design. You have an object (`Data`) that is shared by multiple threads. This object should be thread-safe. Suppose someone adds a Thread C in future and forgets to enforce the happens-before relationship. This will introduce hard to find synchronization errors that usually take a very long time to identify since they happen intermittently or rarely.

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware of the design issue, but I'm aiming for a well performing communication with 0 garbage produced. I though volatile only ensured that the volatile-marked variable was flushed on writes, a.k.a not stale, not all thread-cached variables. But it seems this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You don't need `volatile` or `synchronized` at all.

Threads A and B never touch the object at the same time, so as long as the hand-off between them establishes a *happens-before* boundary, they will always see the latest data.

For example, if the queue is a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), you get this guarantee:

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a `BlockingQueue` *happen-before* actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the `BlockingQueue` in another thread.

So as long as the queue is a `BlockingQueue`, not a generic [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), the hand-off from thread A to thread B is safe.

If the signal from thread B back to thread A is doing using e.g. a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), you get this guarantee:

> Memory consistency effects: Until the count reaches zero, actions in a thread prior to calling `countDown()` *happen-before* actions following a successful return from a corresponding `await()` in another thread.

So the hand-off from thread B back to thread A is also safe.

**Summary:**

- Everything thread A does *before* sending the object *happens before* thread B receives the object.
- Everything thread B does *before* sending the signal *happens before* thread A receives the signal.

**Conclusion:**

There is no need `volatile` or `synchronized`.

Comment: That's good news. Unfortunately, I don't establish any happens-before boundary that I know of. The two threads communicate by assigning volatile pointers. For instance, when B finishes with data, it assigns a null pointer to data's pointer, which A in turn polls during the execution of B. my queue is a different story, but it's not a blocking queue. So let's play with the thought that I don't establish anything. What do you have to say then?